# Function does not return the list correctly

Tags: function, python-3.x

I have written a code for adding the numbers from two different text files. For a very big data 2-3 GB, I get the MemoryError. So, I am writing a new code using some functions to avoid loading the whole data into memory.

This code opens an input file 'd.txt' an reads the numbers after some lines from a bigger data as following:

```
SCALAR
ND    3
ST    0
TS    1000
1.0
1.0
1.0
SCALAR
ND    3
ST    0
TS    2000
3.3
3.4
3.5
SCALAR
ND    3
ST    0
TS    3000
1.7
1.8
1.9
```

and adds to the number have read from a smaller text file 'e.txt' as following:

```
SCALAR
ND    3
ST    0
TS    0
10.0
10.0
10.0
```

The result is written in a text file 'output.txt' like this:

```
SCALAR
ND    3
ST    0
TS    1000
11.0
11.0
11.0
SCALAR
ND    3
ST    0
TS    2000
13.3
13.4
13.5
SCALAR
ND    3
ST    0
TS    3000
11.7
11.8
11.9
```

The code which I prepared:

```
def add_list_same(list1, list2):
    """
    list2 has the same size as list1
    """
    c = [a+b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
    print(c)
    return c


def list_numbers_after_ts(n, f):
    result = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('TS'):
            for node in range(n):
                result.append(float(next(f)))
    return result


def writing_TS(f1):
    TS = []
    ND = []
    for line1 in f1:
        if line1.startswith('ND'):
            ND = float(line1.split()[-1])
        if line1.startswith('TS'):
            x = float(line1.split()[-1])
            TS.append(x)
    return TS, ND


with open('d.txt') as depth_dat_file, \
     open('e.txt') as elev_file, \
     open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    m = writing_TS(depth_dat_file)
    print('number of TS', m[1])
    for j in range(0,int(m[1])-1):
        i = m[1]*j
        out.write('SCALAR\nND  {0:2f}\nST   0\nTS  {0:2f}\n'.format(m[1], m[0][j]))
        list1 = list_numbers_after_ts(int(m[1]), depth_dat_file)
        list2 = list_numbers_after_ts(int(m[1]), elev_file)
        Eh = add_list_same(list1, list2)
        out.writelines(["%.2f\n" % item  for item in Eh])
```

the output.txt is like this:

```
SCALAR
ND    3.000000
ST    0
TS    3.000000
SCALAR
ND    3.000000
ST    0
TS    3.000000
SCALAR
ND    3.000000
ST    0
TS    3.000000
```

The addition of lists does not work, besides I checked separately the functions, they work. I don't find the error. I changed it a lot, but it does not work. Any suggustion? I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grouper` to read files by fixed count of lines. Next code should works if order of lines in groups is unchanged.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

#Split by group iterator
#See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks
def grouper(iterable, n, padvalue=None):
  return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)

add_numbers = []

with open("e.txt") as f:
    # Read data by 7 lines
    for lines in grouper(f, 7): 
        # Suppress first SCALAR line
        for line in lines[1:]:
            # add last number in every line to array (6 elements)
            add_numbers.append(float(line.split()[-1].strip())) 

#template for every group
template = 'SCALAR\nND {:.2f}\nST {:.2f}\nTS {:.2f}\n{:.2f}\n{:.2f}\n{:.2f}\n'

with open("d.txt") as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    # As before
    for lines in grouper(f, 7):
        data_numbers = []
        for line in lines[1:]: 
            data_numbers.append(float(line.split()[-1].strip())) 
        # in result_numbers sum elements of two arrays by pair (6 elements)
        result_numbers = [x + y for x, y in zip(data_numbers, add_numbers)]
        # * unpack result_numbers as 6 arguments of function format
        out.write(template.format(*result_numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change some small things in the code and now it works but just for small input files, because many variables are loaded into memory. Can you please tell me how can I work with yield.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, padvalue=None):
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)


def writing_ND(f1):
    for line1 in f1:
        if line1.startswith('ND'):
            ND = float(line1.split()[-1])
            return ND


def writing_TS(f):
    for line2 in f:
        if line2.startswith('TS'):
            x = float(line2.split()[-1])
            TS.append(x)
    return TS
TS = []
ND = []
x = 0.0
n = 0
add_numbers = []

with open("e.txt") as f, open("d.txt") as f1,\
     open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    ND = writing_ND(f)
    TS = writing_TS(f1)
    n = int(ND)+4
    f.seek(0)
    for lines in grouper(f, int(n)):
        for item in lines[4:]:
            add_numbers.append(float(item))
    i = 0
    for l in grouper(f1, n):
        data_numbers = []
        for line in l[4:]:
            data_numbers.append(float(line.split()[-1].strip()))
            result_numbers = [x + y for x, y in zip(data_numbers, add_numbers)]
        del data_numbers
        out.write('SCALAR\nND    %d\nST  0\nTS      %0.2f\n' % (ND, TS[i]))
        i += 1
        for item in result_numbers:
            out.write('%s\n' % item)
```